# Hellsing English Dub

Tags: anime

I was watching Hellsing OVA in an English dub and I was wondering when the 6th episode in English will come out. If you could tell me, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific about which "next episode" you're referring to.

- [Episodes 5-8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008YRL7H6) will be released on Region 1 DVD and BluRay on November 13, 2012.
- [Episode 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hellsing_episodes#Hellsing_Ultimate) was released in Japan on February 15, 2012 but there have been no announcements as to its availability outside Japan.
- Episode 10 has not been released yet at all.  There are reports of a December 21, 2012 airing date in Japan but these may just be fake rumours.

Comment: Apologies. I edited my post. Thanks for that.